# php preg_replace strings except inside url

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to replace some word in the string. But the word inside the urls should not be replaced
I don't know how to make a pattern that has a condition!

```
$str = 'hi iam working in shop. my shop address is: <br />
        <a href="https://example.com/shop">shop</a> and my shop logo is: <br /> 
       <img src="https://example.com/shop/shop-logo.png">';

$replace = 'store';

$patern = '/shop/';

echo preg_replace($patern,$replace,$str);
```

Comment: you can use lookahead and lookbehind
'/(?<= )shop(?= |\.)/'

Comment: Thank you. That's what I wanted. I didn't understand why my question was closed!